# How to setParams in `Screen` when use `TabNavigator`(ES6)?

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

(Android React-Native 0.47)

How could i do to give the two `PopularTab` diff `params` and get this `params` in `PopularTab`, I've try many times ,but failed.
the only `params` i can get is `navigation.key` and `navigation.routeName`:

```
const Popular = TabNavigator({
  IOS: {
     screen: PopularTab,
     //I try to code here to set the params but fail.
     //eg:  data: 'param1'
      },
  Android: {
    screen: PopularTab,
      },
   },
{
   tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
   tabBarOptions: {
   activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
    }
  }
 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways to achieve this, see which suits your need.

### 1. Suggest to do this official way, via screenProps

`screenProps` seems also suit your needs, with unidirectional design pattern.

**helper function**

```js
function ScreenWithDefaultParams(Comp, defaultParams) {
    return class extends Component {
        render() {
            return (<Comp {...this.props} screenProps={defaultParams} />)
        }
    }
}
```

**TabNavigation definition**

```js
IOS: {
    screen: ScreenWithDefaultParams(PopularTab, {test: 'default'})
},
```

**And then you can get it inside `PopularTab`:**

```js
class PopularTab extends Component {
    render() {
        /* get default screenProps */
        console.log('default screenProps here!', this.props.screenProps);
    }
}
```

### 2. Workaround for set default navigation params

Although it works, there's some problem with it. Firstly, as you see you got warning about **Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern**, that is because every time you call setParams, navigationOptions will be trigger again so react-native warn you that might be an anti-pattern, or might cause an infinite loop.

Although we know it won't be an infinite loop, the warning won't disappear because react-native compiler never satisfied with it.

**helper function**

```js
function setDefaultParams(nav, defaultParams) {
    const { state, setParams } = nav.navigation;
    const params = state.params || {};

    let token = btoa(JSON.stringify(defaultParams));
    if (params[token]) return;

    setParams({ [token]: true, ...defaultParams });
}
```

**TabNavigation definition**

```js
IOS: {
    screen: PopularTab,
    navigationOptions: (nav) => {
        setDefaultParams(nav, {test: 'default'});
    }
},
```

**And then you can get it inside `PopularTab`:**

```js
class PopularTab extends Component {
    render() {
        const { state, setParams, navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        const params = state.params || {};

        /* get default set params */
        console.log('default param here!', params.test);
    }
}
```

### 3. set component props in navigators

If you want to make it happens with normal `Component` `props`:

**TabNavigation definition**

```js
IOS: {
    screen: (props) => <PopularTab {...props} test='default' />,
},
```

**And then you can get it inside `PopularTab`:**

```js
class PopularTab extends Component {
    render() {
        /* get default props */
        console.log('default props here!', this.props.test);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank U, It did works. but some warning come out.Is there any way which i can use to send params or what shou i do if i want re-use the `PopularTab` instead of write two high similary `Component`.

Comment: There's another way to achieve this, modified my answer. please have a look =)